# Optimizing pandas iteration

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization, iteration

```
Customer  Year   Customer Lost/Retained
A         2009          Retained
A         2010          Retained   
A         2011          Lost
B         2008          Lost
C         2008          Retained
C         2009          lost
```

I have used itterrows() for creating Customer Lost/Retained column based on the above logic.

If a customer is duplicated for the consecutive year, he is retained else lost.

```
for i, row in df.iterrows(): 
    if (df[df['Year'] == row['Year']+1]['Customer']).str.contains(df['Customer'].iloc[i]).any():
        df['Customer Lost/Retained'].iloc[i] = 'Retained'
    else:
        df['Customer Lost/Retained'].iloc[i] = 'Lost'
```

Can this code be optimized further?

Answer (score 2):

```
# groupby customer
g = df.groupby('Customer')['Year']
# create a mask of conditions by using shift
mask = (g.shift(0) == g.shift(-1)-1)
# use npy.wehre to create a list of results based on the mask
df['Retained/lost'] = np.where(mask, 'Retained', 'Lost')

  Customer  Year Retained/lost
0        A  2009      Retained
1        A  2010      Retained
2        A  2011          Lost
3        B  2008          Lost
4        C  2008      Retained
5        C  2009          Lost
```

Comment: This one relies on having the years in sorted order but is otherwise a nice solution

Comment: @Randy yes, it does. I forgot to mention that in the solution. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this as a `merge` with itself but modifying the year:

```
In [83]: df['retained'] = pd.notnull(df.merge(
    ...:     df,
    ...:     how="left",
    ...:     left_on=["Customer", "Year"],
    ...:     right_on=["Customer", df["Year"].sub(1)],
    ...:     suffixes=['', "_match"]
    ...: )["Year_match"]).map({True: 'Retained', False: 'Lost'})

In [84]: df
Out[84]:
  Customer  Year Customer Lost/Retained  retained
0        A  2009               Retained  Retained
1        A  2010               Retained  Retained
2        A  2011                   Lost      Lost
3        B  2008                   Lost      Lost
4        C  2008               Retained  Retained
5        C  2009                   lost      Lost
```

Comment: Great solution. I always like seeing the different ways people work to solve the same problem. Never would have even though about `merge` as an option +1

Answer (score 0):

We add a column which says `'Retained'`:

```py
df['Customer Lost/Retained'] = 'Retained'
```

Except for the indices with the highest year per customer, they get value `'Lost'`:

```py
mask = df.groupby('Customer')['Year'].idxmax()
df.loc[mask, 'Customer Lost/Retained'] = 'Lost'
```

```py
  Customer  Year Customer Lost/Retained
0        A  2009               Retained
1        A  2010               Retained
2        A  2011                   Lost
3        B  2008                   Lost
4        C  2008               Retained
5        C  2009                   Lost
```

Or, alternatively, insert the `'Lost'` first and then [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```py
df.loc[df.groupby('Customer')['Year'].idxmax(), 'Customer Lost/Retained'] = 'Lost'
df['Customer Lost/Retained'] = df['Customer Lost/Retained'].fillna('Retained')
```

Comment: This only works if there are no gaps in years in the data.

Comment: Yes, assumption here is that customers cannot be lost multiple times.

Comment: Which is in line with OP's requirement right: "if a customer is duplicated for the consecutive year, he is retained else lost".

Comment: My interpretation of that was that a customer with years 2008, 2009, 2011, and 2012 would count as lost for both 2009 and 2012 due to the 2010 gap.

Comment: This did not work because it took the value as 'Retained' if the customer is present in max year. My case is if Customer A in 2008 is present in 2009 then A in 2008 is Retained. This code gave A as retained even if he is present in 2010 or 2011.

Comment: What? I don't understand your reply. My code's output is exactly the same as your expected output in the question, right?